# Can't use targets and report not working on Firebase Messaging on iOS and ReactNative

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have installed [Firebase Messaging for React Native](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage) on Android and iOS and both are receiving notifications. On Android I can target different users correctly and in the reports it updates the four items (Sends, Received, Impressions, Open count), but on iOS if I use any target the notification won't be sent to any device, and it only counts the Sends.

For example:

- Target the app in general: 100% of potential users are eligible for this campaign:5
- Target the app and language **is** in English: 0% of potential users are eligible for this campaign:0
- Target the app and language **is not** in English: 0% of potential users are eligible for this campaign:0

We have only tested in from xCode and Testflight

I have tried it on different iPhones from xCode and Tesflight, using debug and release builds.

I expect to be able to filter by targets on Firebase Messaging when creating a campaign, to send notifications on different languages, to different app versions etc

What I get instead is only the option to send and receive notifications, without being able to filter and receive stats of how many have been open

I have followed the guide from https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there may be an issue with the way you are targeting users on iOS using Firebase Messaging. Here are a few things you can try to troubleshoot the issue:

Make sure that you have followed the instructions for setting up Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) on iOS, as this is required for Firebase Messaging to work properly on the platform.

Check that the devices you are targeting on iOS have registered for push notifications using the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK. You can do this by checking the Firebase console for your project and looking at the list of registered devices.

Try sending a notification to all devices on iOS and see if it works. If it does, then the issue may be with your targeting criteria.

Double-check that your targeting criteria are set up correctly. For example, if you are targeting users based on their language, make sure that the language codes you are using match the ones that are set on the user's device.

Check the Firebase Cloud Messaging API logs to see if there are any errors or warnings that might indicate what the problem is.

If none of these steps help resolve the issue, you may want to reach out to Firebase support for additional assistance.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it again.What I did instead was to create a topic based on the language of the app (named english-notification, italian-notification, etc) so the user gets subscribed to it, and then in the "Target" section, instead of using "User segment" I use "Topic". This works all fine and it also autocompletes every topic and shows how many users they target (although like <1000, 1K-10K, etc, so not as precise)